# pt-table-checksum and mysql 5.7 with binlog_format=ROW

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-tools

How to use `pt-table-checksum` in mysql 5.7 where `binlog_format=ROW` is default

I also need `binlog_format=ROW` to be set this way in relation to other parameters in the mysql configuration

```
# pt-table-checksum h=localhost,u=checksum,p=xxx
Replica Worker-Intel-i7-2600-16gb has binlog_format ROW which could cause pt-table-checksum to break replication.  Please read "Replicas using row-based replication" in the LIMITATIONS section of the tool's documentation.  If you understand the risks, specify --no-check-binlog-format to disable this check.
```

I have tried to read about the limitations, but doesn't really understand what would/could happen if `--no-check-binlog-format` is used

If I set `binlog_format=MIXED` I still get the error!?

Answer (score 1):

with --no-check-binlog-format you would not be able to checksum from master to cascading slaves aside from master's immediate replicas, --no-check-binlog-format also sets the tool's session to STATEMENT format but does not change the global status. there should not be any issues when you use the option but we recommend you test them first.

Comment: What would be the worst thing that could happen?

Comment: probably slave replication lag if you don't use options in the tool to check slave lag, but pt-tc should only checksum the data and only write to the checksum table.