# mysql master-slave replication and status of data consistency

Tags: mysql, replication

I have setup a master-slave replication with mysql 5.7 and GTID.

GTID should be more "safe" than the older way where each statement alone was replicated right?

But when replicating with GTID can I then check the data consistency on the slave just by checking `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` ?

Or do I need to checksum each row in each table to make sure everything is replicated correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I address your question, some terminology issues...

`GTID` uniquely identifies each thing replicated.  This is an improvement on the previous Replication technology -- but mostly when you have multiple machines and need to recover from some kind of failure.  It helps automate things.

`bin_log_format` = STATEMENT or ROW or MIXED refers to what is transferred from Master to Slave.  STATEMENT (SBR) is the old way; ROW (RBR) is the new way.  There are many subtle reasons why RBR is 'better'.

`SHOW SLAVE STATUS` provides, among other things, whether or not replication has stopped due to some error.  It reports a crude measure of staleness (`Seconds_Behind_Master`), but not "consistency" (whether the changes arrived and were correctly applied).

You do not need a checksum on each row.  It would be clumsy for you to add such.  The network layer (TCP/IP, etc) does checksumming to 'guarantee' delivery and to validate the contents of the delivery.

If you want to do your own consistency checking, I recommend Percona's [*`pt-table-checksum`*](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-checksum.html) .  It takes care of a lot of end-cases that are not obvious to someone starting out to do the checking himself.

Comment: Ok thanks for the good answer.. But this lead me to another question I asked a couple of days ago.. Hope you could be helpful :) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175030/pt-table-checksum-and-mysql-5-7-with-binlog-format-row